# Не запускается второе activity через intent в kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, activity

У меня есть 2 activity: LevelActivity.kt , GameActivity.kt
В LevelActivity.kt я создал несколько методов, которые создают Intent(action) и которые вызываются в зависимости от того, какой уровень сложности выбрал пользователь.

```
fun playEasy(view: View) {
    val intent = Intent(ACTION_EASY)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

При работе приложения, когда выбираешь уровень сложности возникает ошибка -
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

В предыдущем проекте на Java, при использовании того же процесса все работало корректно.
Помогите плиз, долго искал решение но так и не нашел

P.S.
Action я объявил в AndroidManifest

```
<activity android:name=".GameActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="info.android.action.easy"/>
            <action android:name="info.android.action.medium"/>
            <action android:name="info.android.action.hard"/>
            <action android:name="info.android.action.impossible"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы запустить `Activity`, нужно вызвать `startActiviity()` метод и передать ему в параметры [Intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters?hl=ru#ExampleExplicit).

Ваш способ, описанный в вопросе, очень интересный, но я бы сделал иначе. Как? Описываю дальше.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setViewClickListeners()
    }

    private fun setViewClickListeners() {
        btnEasy.setOnClickListener { startGameActivity(GameDifficulty.EASY_GAME) }
        btnMedium.setOnClickListener { startGameActivity(GameDifficulty.MEDIUM_GAME) }
        btnHard.setOnClickListener { startGameActivity(GameDifficulty.HARD_GAME) }
        btnImpossible.setOnClickListener { startGameActivity(GameDifficulty.IMPOSSIBLE_GAME) }
    }

    private fun startGameActivity(gameDifficulty: GameDifficulty) = startActivity(GameActivity.getEasyGameIntent(this, gameDifficulty))
}


class GameActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        private const val KEY_GAME_VARIANT = "key_game_variant"

        fun getGameIntent(context: Context, gameDifficulty: GameDifficulty): Intent =
            Intent(context, GameActivity::class.java).putExtra(
                KEY_GAME_VARIANT,
                gameDifficulty.toString()
            )
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)

        val gameDifficultyString: String? = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_GAME_VARIANT)
        gameDifficultyString.let {
            Toast.makeText(this, it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}

enum class GameDifficulty {
    EASY_GAME,
    MEDIUM_GAME,
    HARD_GAME,
    IMPOSSIBLE_GAME
}
```

В будущем можно будет модифицировать `enum` класс `GameDifficulty`, чтобы он хранил в себе варианты `DeBuff`'a соперников или иной другой тип данных нужного уровня сложности.
Будет выглядеть это так

```
enum class GameDifficulty(enemyDeBuff: Int) {
    EASY_GAME(5),
    MEDIUM_GAME(15),
    HARD_GAME(35),
    IMPOSSIBLE_GAME(60)
}
```

или так

```
enum class GameDifficulty(enemyDeBuff: Int, heroAttack: Int) {
    EASY_GAME(5, 75),
    MEDIUM_GAME(15, 60),
    HARD_GAME(35, 45),
    IMPOSSIBLE_GAME(60, 30)
}
```

И через сериализацию, к примеру библиотекой от `Google` `Gson`, доставать эти значения. Но это уже совсем <s>другая история</s> другой вопрос.

Comment: спасибо большое за подробный ответ))
немного туплю, так как после джавы на котлине немного непривычно писать

Comment: @RostyslavYanchynsky, успехов в разработке игры! ;-)